# Finding the path to a file from terminal

Tags: files, filesystem, paths, locate

I am trying to retrieve the path to a Java class file. I have 2 projects in my eclipse: `project_a` and `project_b`. I navigated to `project_a`'s `bin` folder and tried the command `locate WebPerformanceUtil.class`. But it gives me four paths:

1. `home/local/prasanth/eclipse/project_a/bin/com/web/utils/WebPerformanceUtil.class`
2. `/home/local/prasanth/eclipse/project_a/bin/com/web/utils/ChromeWebPerformanceUtil.class`
3. `/home/local/prasanth/eclipse/project_b/bin/com/web/utils/WebPerformanceUtil.class`
4. `/home/local/prasanth/eclipse/project_b/bin/com/web/utils/ChromeWebPerformanceUtil.class`

But I want only the path which contains the the `bin` folder of the project which I'm working in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find . -type f -name WebPerformanceUtil.class
```

where `.` is `~/eclipse/project_folder`

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command:

```
locate WebPerformanceUtil.class | grep $(pwd)
```

- `grep $(pwd)` displays only the matches found under your current working directory (`/home/local/prasanth/eclipse/project_a/` in your case).

**After your edit:**

Since you only want the exact filename, you can also use regular expressions with `locate`. The command is the following:

```
locate -r '\<WebPerformanceUtil.class\>' | grep $(pwd)
```

- The `-r` parameter tells `locate` to use regular expressions.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I have a file called ChromeWebPerformanceUtil.class and that too is getting listed, how can I avoid that?